# Sound on mouseover, stop on mouseout - DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Tags: javascript

can someone help me with sound on mouseover? I don't know what I'm doing wrong - here is my code and side.

http://ourworlds.pl

```
<script>
        function PlaySound(soundobj) {
            var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
            thissound.play();
        }

        function StopSound(soundobj) {
            var thissound = document.getElementById(soundobj);
            thissound.pause();
            thissound.currentTime = 0;
        }
    </script>


<body>
    <a href="http://ourworlds.pl/Forum/#49" onmouseover="PlaySound('horse)" onmouseout="StopSound('horse')" target="_blank"><div id="cz1"></div></a>
    <a href="http://ourworlds.pl/Forum/#1" onmouseover="PlaySound('beep')" onmouseout="StopSound('beep')" target="_blank"><div id="cz2"></div></a>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

    <audio id='horse' src='beep.mp3' />
    <audio id='beep' src='horse.mp3' />
    
</body>
```

Comment: Modern browsers blocks play until the user has interacted with the page (usually clicked on something on the page). In Google Chrome you can enable sound for a specific site, if you want to allow that site to play audio without interaction.

Comment: @Finarfin try `alert("Welcome user!");` or something along those lines as the first thing shown to user - just to see if sound plays as desired after the first interaction is done.

Comment: There are no other ways? I would not like to apply alerts on my side. I would like the website to look nice :)

Comment: Your web site uses `.setAttribute("muted", false)`. That’s not how you set boolean attributes. Use `.muted = false` instead. Same for `true`.